# Actualizar una grafica sin refrescar la pagina

Tags: php, html, mysql

Muy buenas gente, tengo una grafica conectada a mi base de datos, en ella me muestra los valores en el eje Y, y el tiempo en el eje X, hasta el momento todo excelente, esta es mi grafica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hacer para que sea una gráfica en línea, osea. E actualice automáticamente cada vez que ingreso datos a la base de datos

el html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>
<!-- Load the AJAX API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" > </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
    'modules':[{
    'name':'visualization',
    'version':'1',
    'packages':['corechart']
    }]
    }">

    </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//llamamos a la función de carga de datos

</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" > </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
    'modules':[{
    'name':'visualization',
    'version':'1',
    'packages':['corechart']
    }]
    }"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="grafico.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<!-- en este div se visualizará la gráfica.-->



<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

el archivo js:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(dibujaGrafica);


function dibujaGrafica() {

var data = $.ajax({
url: "cargaDatos.php",
dataType:"json",
async: false
}).responseText;

//para que se lea correctamente el array enviado por JSON usamos JSON.parse
var infoGraf = JSON.parse(data);

//Creamos y rellenamos la tabla de datos
var datoFinal = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(infoGraf);

//en la parte de options puede personalizarse la gráfica, como títulos, colores...
var options = {
title: 'Grafica Valores',
curveType: 'function',
legend: { position: 'bottom' }
};


var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
chart.draw(datoFinal, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede añadir una llamada  a la función `dibujaGrafica` cada **X** segundos para que se actualice.

```
// setInterval(NombreFuncion, TiempoMilisegundos);
setInterval(dibujaGrafica, 3000);
```

[Documentación setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Quedando algo así:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(dibujaGrafica);


function dibujaGrafica() {

var data = $.ajax({
url: "cargaDatos.php",
dataType:"json",
async: false
}).responseText;

//para que se lea correctamente el array enviado por JSON usamos JSON.parse
var infoGraf = JSON.parse(data);

//Creamos y rellenamos la tabla de datos
var datoFinal = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(infoGraf);

//en la parte de options puede personalizarse la gráfica, como títulos, colores...
var options = {
title: 'Grafica Valores',
curveType: 'function',
legend: { position: 'bottom' }
};


var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
chart.draw(datoFinal, options);
}
// Añadimos esta linea
setInterval(dibujaGrafica, 3000);
```

Comment: No te olvides de marcar tu respuesta como la correcta después de 48 horas

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente esa era la solucion, pero el setInterval iba  ubicado era en el codigo html, no en el javascrip, pero de igual muchas gracias  por la ayuda,